# On the proof of The Bounded Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

From the text Real Analysis by Royden, he gives the following proposition

---

**Proposition 8:** Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of bounded measurable functions on a set of finite
measure $E$.

$$\text{If } \{f_n\}\to f \text{ uniformly on $E$, then } \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}f_n = \int_{E}f.$$

The proof is given as:

*Proof:* Since the convergence is uniform and each $f_n$ is bounded, the limit function $f$ is
bounded. The function $f$ is measurable since it is the pointwise limit of a sequence of
measurable functions. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose an index $N$ for which

$$\left|f-f_n\right|<\epsilon/\operatorname{m}\left(E\right)\text{ on $E$ for all $n\geq N$}.$$

By the linearity and monotonicity of integration and the preceding corollary, for each $n\geq N$,

$$\left|\int_{E}f - \int_{E}f_n\right| = \left|\int_{E}[f - f_n]\right|\leq\int_{E}\left|f-f_n\right|\leq [\epsilon/\operatorname{m}\left(E\right)]\cdot\operatorname{m}\left(E\right) = \epsilon.$$

Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}f_n = \int_{E}f$.

---

My question is: How come if we switch bounded to uniformly bounded, and uniform convergent to pointwise convergent the proof no longer holds? Moreover, how come we can not longer say: Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose an index $N$ for which

$$\left|f-f_n\right|<\epsilon/\operatorname{m}\left(E\right)\text{ on $E$ for all $n\geq N$}.$$

Is this statement no longer true if $\{f_n\}\to f \text{ pointwise on $E$}$?

Comment: To your last questioin: indeed, this is no longer true.

Comment: "Is this statement no longer true if $\{f_n\} \to f$ pointwise on E" That's exactly the problem. With pointwise convergence the best you can say is that for each $x$, there exists an $N_x$ such that $|f(x)-f_n(x)| < \epsilon/m(E)$ for all $n \geq N_x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all that you assume is that $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwise to $f$, then all you know is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ for each individual $x\in E$. But you cannot deduce from this that, given $\varepsilon>0$, you have $\bigl|f(x)-f_n(x)\bigr|$ for every sufficiently large $N$ and for *all* $x\in E$.

For instance, take $E=[0,1]$. For each $x\in E$ and each $n\in\Bbb N$, defined$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n^2x&\text{ if }x<\frac1{2n}\\-n^2\left(x-\frac1n\right)&\text{ if }x\in\left[\frac1{2n},\frac1n\right]\\0&\text{ if }x>\frac1n,\end{cases}$$Then $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwise to the null function, but, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $\int_0^1f_n(x)\,\mathrm dx=\frac14$.

Comment: Nice use of hats!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

If the $(f_n)$ are uniformly bounded and converge pointwise to $f$, the condition
$$
|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon/m(E)\qquad\forall x\in E\ \forall n\ge N\tag1$$
may never be satisfied.  As a counterexample, on $E:=[0,1]$ consider $f_n$ to be a rectangle of height $1$ over the interval $(0,\frac1n)$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is always a set $A$ of positive measure where $|f-f_n|>\epsilon$ on $A$. So the proof doesn't go through using (1). (The result that $\int f_n\to\int f$ is still true, though, by dominated convergence.)

Comment: Could you explain the part where you say "Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is always a set $A$ of positive measure where $|f-f_n|>\epsilon$ on $A$"? I am not really seeing how this is the case!

Comment: $f_n(x)=1$ for all $x\in (0,\frac1n)$. So given $\epsilon<1$ and $N$, take any $n\ge N$, and define $A:=(0,\frac1n)$. For such $n$ we have $f_n(x)>\epsilon$ for all $x\in A$, so (1) fails.

Comment: I see now. Thanks!

Comment: To summarize: The proof of the BCT asserts $\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists N$ such that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon/m(E)$ for all $x\in E$ $\forall n\ge N$. To show the assertion is false, you need to demonstrate the negation of that assertion, which is: "there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N$ there exists $x\in E$ and $n\ge N$ such that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\ge\epsilon / m(E)$".